# Classify all $A\in M_5(\mathbb{Q}):A^8=I$ and $A^4\not=I$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

> Classify all $A\in M_5(\mathbb{Q}):A^8=I$ and $A^4\not=I$

**Attempt**

Since $A^8=I$ it must be $m_A(x)|x^8-1=(x-1)(x+1)(x^2+1)(x^4+1)$. But $A^4\not=I$ so $m_A(x)\not=x-1,x+1,x^2-1,x^2+1,x^4-1,(x-1)(x^2+1),(x+1)(x^2+1)$

And $A\in M_5(\mathbb{Q})\Rightarrow \deg(\chi_A(x))=5$

How should I continue? Hoe would you approach this question?

I want to find the similarity classes using rational normal form.

I know that $\chi_A(x)=$product of the prime divisors of $A$ and $m_A(x)=$lcm of the prime divisors of $A$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its minimal polynomial, and so its characteristic polynomial $p(x)$, must have $x^4+1$
as a factor. So $p(x)=(x-\alpha)(x^4+1)$
for some $\alpha$. But then $\alpha\in\Bbb Q$ and there aren't many
possibilities for it...

In all cases $p(x)$ will be squarefree, so the RCF
for $A$ will be the companion matrix of $p(x)$.

Comment: So $\alpha=\pm 1$?? and characteristic polynomial $p(x)=(x\pm1)(x^4+1)$ and minimal  polynomial  $m(x)=(x^4+1)(x\pm1)$ ??

Comment: That's right! @giannispapav

Comment: ok thanks. Could you explain "must have $x^4+1$ as a factor"?? Is there a quick way to prove that? Because in order to exclude $m(x)=(x-1)(x^2+1)$ I calculated that $(A-I)(A^2+I)=0\Rightarrow A^4=I$ by hand

Comment: You did that in your answer! The point is that the other irreducible factors of $x^8-1$ are all factors of $x^4-1$.

Comment: aaa ok I see, thanks!